# WCF netTcpBinding & ASP.NET MembershipProvider without PrincipalPermission attribute

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-security, nettcpbinding

I have a WCF Service, using netTcpBinding, and a custom ASP.NET Membership Provider (reads users from a config file on the Server; will be ServiceAccounts). Transport Security is to the defaults.

I am using the PrincipalPermssions attribute to say for this method, the user must be in this role.

- Works perfectly well

**Question**
The membership provider only seems to kick-in, if the PrincipalPermssions attribute is on the Service Method.

Is there a way of applying a Membership Provider authentication to all the Service Methods, regardless of the attribute?

Or is there another way of locking down all Service Methods by default?
- Rather than just the user is a valid Windows User.

Answer (score 0):

From the book Programming WCF Services:

> While the PrincipalPermission attribute by its very definition can be applied on
>   methods and classes, in a WCF service class you can apply it only on methods. The
>   reason is that in WCF, unlike with normal classes, the service class constructor always
>   executes under a GenericPrincipal with a blank identity, regardless of the authentication mechanisms used. As a result, the identity under which the constructor is running is unauthenticated and will always fail any kind of authorization attempt (even if
>   the client is a member of the role and even when not using Windows groups)

I suggest that you provide an Initialize method if you are using sessions where you can initialize the service instance and authorize the callers.